# How to configure the default ObjectMapper used by Spring to use a custom deserializer when deserializing spring classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I want to use my own custom deserializer in Spring's default ObjectMapper whenever I have a class of type OAuth2AccessToken. The interface is annotated with

```
JsonDeserialize(using = OAuth2AccessTokenJackson2Deserializer.class)
```

and this is what it's using at the moment to deserialize but I want to use my own.

So far I have created my own custom deserializer

```java
public class MyCustomDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<OAuth2AccessToken> {

    public MyCustomDeserializer() {
        super(OAuth2AccessToken.class);
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String tokenValue = null;
        String tokenType = null;
        String refreshToken = null;
        Long expiresIn = null;
        Set<String> scope = null;
        Map<String, Object> additionalInformation = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

        while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            String name = jp.getCurrentName();
            jp.nextToken();

            if (OAuth2AccessToken.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(name)) {
                tokenValue = jp.getText();
            } else if (OAuth2AccessToken.TOKEN_TYPE.equals(name)) {
                tokenType = jp.getText();
            } else if (OAuth2AccessToken.REFRESH_TOKEN.equals(name)) {
                refreshToken = jp.getText();
            } else if (OAuth2AccessToken.EXPIRES_IN.equals(name)) {
                try {
                    expiresIn = jp.getLongValue();
                } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                    expiresIn = Long.valueOf(jp.getText());
                }
            } else if (OAuth2AccessToken.SCOPE.equals(name)) {
                scope = parseScope(jp);
            } else {
                additionalInformation.put(name, jp.readValueAs(Object.class));
            }
        }

        DefaultOAuth2AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultOAuth2AccessToken(tokenValue);
        accessToken.setTokenType(tokenType);
        if (expiresIn != null) {
            accessToken.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (expiresIn * 1000)));
        }
        if (refreshToken != null) {
            accessToken.setRefreshToken(new DefaultOAuth2RefreshToken(refreshToken));
        }
        accessToken.setScope(scope);
        accessToken.setAdditionalInformation(additionalInformation);

        return accessToken;
    }

    private Set<String> parseScope(JsonParser jp) throws JsonParseException, IOException {
        Set<String> scope;
        if (jp.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
            scope = new TreeSet<String>();
            while (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
                scope.add(jp.getValueAsString());
            }
        } else {
            String text = jp.getText();
            scope = OAuth2Utils.parseParameterList(text);
        }
        return scope;
    }
}
```

My own custom class by extending DefaultOAuth2AccessToken

```java
@com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize(using = MyCustomDeserializer.class)
public class MyCustomOAuth2AccessToken extends DefaultOAuth2AccessToken {

    public MyCustomOAuth2AccessToken(String value) {
        super(value);
    }

    public MyCustomOAuth2AccessToken(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken) {
        super(accessToken);
    }
}
```

and at the moment I am registering a bean of type Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer like this

```java
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomDeserialization() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
            SimpleModule m = new SimpleModule();
            m.addDeserializer(OAuth2AccessToken.class, new MyCustomDeserializer());
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.modules(m);
        }
    };
}

@Bean
public OAuth2ClientContext getOAuth2ClientContext() {
    DefaultOAuth2ClientContext defaultOAuth2ClientContext = new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext();
    defaultOAuth2ClientContext.setAccessToken(new MyCustomOAuth2AccessToken("test"));
    return defaultOAuth2ClientContext;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply annotate your deserialization classes with **@JsonComponent**.
The annotation allows us to expose an annotated class to be a Jackson serializer and/or deserializer without the need to add it to the ObjectMapper manually.

Comment: It is worth to mention, that this doesn't work with the @EnableWebMvc annotation. So for anyone reading, remove the EnableWebMvc annotation and you can freely use JsonComponent. I might save you 2 hours...

Answer (score 0):

To configure ObjectMapper globally just create a bean of type `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` and use `deserializerByType` method :

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
  return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
           .deserializerByType(OAuth2AccessToken.class, new MyCustomDeserializer());
}
```

Reference of configuring ObjectMapper in SpringBoot can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

Comment: Still can't hit my deserializer class. I tried Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer still the same.

Comment: Are you sure that it is Jackson's object mapper used to deserialize your data? Do you send this token as JSON to your spring endpoints? Where is the deserialization taking place?

Comment: So after further investigation I found one more custom objectmapper marked as @Primary in one of my libraries. Here https://imgur.com/jpk5yas is exactly the point of getting the deserializer inside ObjectMapper _findRootDeserializer method.